# What is the right approach to include Xlab packages for development?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am new to xamarin and using XLab packages. I can see that Xlab packages are not stable yet however community is strongly supporting. In test
project I have added packages using Nugets. Now I found one issue in camera API of it so, how should I fix it. I have just
library files so, I can see code or fix it immediately.

Should I include the code of it? Because I can't wait for community to fix the issue and get the updated package of it? Yes If I will fix something then
I would love to contribute to open source community.

FYI: I am using PCL approach for development.

Answer (score 0):

Best option would be to fork the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs) and work on the sample application.

You can also [get a copy of the source without cloning](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/archive/master.zip) but then you cannot create a pull request for any code fixes. You can still report any bugs you find but it will be easier to contribute to the project by forking the project.